# I am trying to display a partial view on the same page as my input form's partial view page but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I want to display the output on the same page where I am taking the input from the user. However, I am not aware of how can I do so. I have a partial page that shows the output which I wish to render in the input form page (can I do that?)

Controller Code

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
    def do_search
        render :partial => "search_form"
    end

    def process_search_data
        @data = Dashboard.new(token: session['token']).get_search_data(search_params)
        #render :partial => "search_form" (not sure if I should render the input page here)
    end

    private

      def search_params
        params.permit(:division_id, :facilities)
      end
```

View Code (**Input Form**)

```
<form action="/dashboards/process_search_data" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>" >
  <div class="form-row" style= "display: inline;">
      <% if @roles['is_system_admin'] || @roles['is_division_admin'] %>
        <div class="col" style="display: inline;">
          <%= label_tag 'facility', t('forms.division'), {class: 'division-lable'} %>
          <%= select_tag 'division_id', options_for_select(@filters['divisions'].map {|key, value| [value, key]}), {class: 'form-control division-select', include_blank: '-'} %>
        </div>
        <div class="col" style="display: inline;">
          <%= label_tag 'facility', t('forms.facility'), {class: 'facility-lable'} %>
          <%= select_tag 'facilities', options_for_select(@filters['facilities'].map {|f| [f['facility_name'], f['facility_id']]}), {class: 'form-control facility-select', include_blank: '-'} %>
        </div>
      <% else %>
        <div class="col" style="display: inline;">
          <%= label_tag 'facility', t('forms.facility'), {class: 'facility-lable'} %>
          <%= select_tag "facilities", options_for_select(@facility_select_options), class: 'form-control facility-select', include_blank: t('facilities.all_facilities') %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <div class="col" style="display: inline-block; width: 150px;">
      <p class="text-right">
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" id="facility_dashboards_search_button" class="button button-primary">
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<%= render :partial => 'cards' %> <!-- is this how I can render the output page here? -->
```

View Code (**Output**)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<% if @data.present? %> 
<% @data.each do |val| %>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://www.webcoderskull.com/img/team1.png">
      <div class="card-block">
          <h7 class="text-bold">Name: <%= val["user_name"] %></h7><br>
          <h7 class="text-bold">Facility: <%= val["facility_name"] %></h7><br>
          <h7 class="text-bold">Company: <%= val["company_name"] %></h7>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your partial is named `_cards.html.erb` then you would render that with `<%= render 'cards' %>` if it's in the same directory.

If you want to access your `@data` instance variable in your cards partial, you need to pass the data into the partial, from where you are rendering it like so:-

`<%= render 'ark_show', locals: { data: @data } %>`, then you can use the `data` variable in your partial.

More info here which may be of use - https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials